# How to clear the keyboard buffer?

Tags: linux

Say an application was asking for keyboard input and I kept a key pressed for a while.

Now the application is responding to the key presses but is slowing down as it progresses.

The idea is to clear all these incoming key presses, stored somewhere in a buffer, so as to have the application stop what it's poorly doing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must indicate which type of application : terminal (POSIX syscall, curses, or stdio API), Qt, Gtk…

If it is a terminal (syscall) you can use the `select` syscall and verify if something is available on the standard input, and while it is true, read it.

It is more a programming question.

Comment: I was doing a bash less command.

Comment: This is a comment, not an actual solution.

Answer (score 2):

I'll answer the title question `How to clear the keyboard buffer?` in the sense that everything that was typed thus far and is perceived to be as an input that is waiting for a program to consume it, will be cleared, and here's how I do it in an executable file(ie. `chmod a+x clrbuf`) called `clrbuf` which silently consumes the input:

```bash
#!/bin/bash
read -r -t 0.1 -s -e --
stty echo echok
exit 0
```

Explanation:
**tl;dr:** silently consume all input, and if there's no input just exit after 0.1 seconds (100ms), then use `stty` to make sure that `read` didn't disable the echo-ing of what the user types, which might happen in certain cases.

This is using /bin/bash's internal `read` command (ie. try `$ help read` while in the `bash` shell, or look at this [doc](https://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_08_02.html)) and using /bin/stty which is part of coreutils package(on Gentoo).

It will read everything that's waiting to be read and ignore it.
For example if you run `sleep 5 ; clrbuf` then you start typing something like `hello`+enter key and stop typing, then after 5 seconds `clrbuf` runs and eats up what you've typed so the terminal prompt afterwards doesn't get that input. Like this:

```bash
$ sleep 5; clrbuf
hello

$ sleep 5; notclrbuf
hello
bash: notclrbuf: command not found
$ hello
bash: hello: command not found
```

The arguments for `read`:
The `--` is not needed, it marks the end of all the arguments, it's just a habbit for me.

```bash
$ read -r --

$ read -- -r
bash: read: `-r': not a valid identifier
```

because there it's expecting a variable identifier where to put the result of the read.

`-r`        "do not allow backslashes to escape any characters. Backslash does not act as an escape character. The backslash is considered to be part of the line. In particular, a backslash-newline pair may not be used as a line continuation." (from `help read` and [that doc](https://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_08_02.html))

```bash
$ read -- a ; echo $a
\\
\

$ read -r -- a ; echo $a
\\
\\
```

`-t TIMEOUT`    "Cause read to time out and return failure if a complete line of input is not read within TIMEOUT seconds. This option has no effect if read is not reading input from the terminal or from a pipe."([from the same doc](https://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_08_02.html)). `-t 0.1` is used to auto exit from `read` after 0.1 seconds when there's no input pending to be consumed.

`-s`    "Silent mode. If input is coming from a terminal, characters are not echoed."([from the same doc](https://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_08_02.html))
For example, if I type "hi"+enter, once:

```bash
$ sleep 5; read  -r -t 0.1  -e -- 
hi
hi

$ sleep 5; read  -r -t 0.1 -s -e -- 
hi
```

`-e`    "readline is used to obtain the line". For some reason I've noted that it doesn't work without this argument. I don't remember why but I noted that it's true for "GNU bash, version 5.0.16(1)-maint (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu) commit 3235014e5b3d227ccd617b0be72d897eb476d23d on devel branch Date:   Mon Apr 20 10:11:53 2020 -0400". For what is worth, I've compiled bash on Gentoo with USE=bundled-readline and maybe that's why it still works without `-e` for me currently. I'm unsure.

`exit 0` is to always make sure to return success from the script, just in case `clrbuf` is used in another bash script which has `set -e` (which would cause that script to exit if an exit code different than 0 happened after calling the `clrbuf` script) ("      -e  Exit immediately if a command exits with a non-zero status.
"). Example:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

set -e
test 20 == 0
#^ our script will exit due to the above, because the above returned exit code 1

echo Done
#^ this is not reached
```

Why is `stty echo echok` needed?
Due to `read -s` (aka silent) which does the equivalent of `stty -echo -echok` (ie. disable `echo` and `echok`), in order to make sure the user isn't ever left without the ability to echo what is typed, in some cases, we make sure the echo-ing is enabled after `read -s` is done.
The following example (c.bash) illustrates when that might happen:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

stty
for i in 1 2 3 4; do
  echo 'a' & #required
  read -r -t 0.1 -s -- &
  #echo "$?" #is 0
done
wait
stty
stty echo echok
```

The output is this:

```
$ ./c.bash 
speed 38400 baud; line = 0;
erase = ^H;
-brkint -imaxbel iutf8
a
a
a
a
speed 38400 baud; line = 0;
erase = ^H;
-brkint -imaxbel iutf8
-echo -echok
```

As you can see at the end `-echo -echok` are new things that are set(to disabled), compared to before calling `read -s ... &` when they were enabled(and thus not printed at all by stty). And the last line `stty echo echok` will make sure to enable them(note that they lack the minus (`-`) prefix), otherwise you won't see what you type on the command prompt (ie. echo-ing of what you type is disabled) after that script exits.
Note that this example isn't the only way to get in this state, but it's an example that helped me reproduce the issue of having the echo disabled when I was using just `read` to `clrbuf`, without `stty`.

A better way might be to save the state of the `echo` and `echok` before the `read -s ...` is invoked and then restore the states afterwards. But this is prone to race conditions (if the program that disabled the echoes re-enables them during our `read -s`, in parallel) and thus risk leaving the user with unechoable terminal(when our `stty` restores them as disabled). Personally, I wouldn't risk implementing this variant.